# Why does css cover not working on "parent" div?

Tags: html, css

I have a class that will be used by multiple DOM elements, of course..
I created the class `.highlight` and to each highlight div, I added an unique `id` to it.

```
.highlight {
    height: 520px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
}
.highlight#pixel { 
    background: url('../images/pixel.jpg') no-repeat center; 
}
```

Each ID has it's own `background-image` via css. I would like to use the css property `background: cover;` to fill in all space with the image.

I thought it would work if you added the cover property to the div `.highlight`, because the id is added to the same div and so I don't have to add the cover property every time to each id in the css, but this doesn't work. Any thoughts why this is not working.

I speak about the following:

```
.highlight {
    height: 520px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.highlight#pixel { 
    background: url('../images/pixel.jpg') no-repeat center; 
}
```

Thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background: url('../images/pixel.jpg') no-repeat center;
```

This is overwriting the `background-size` rule in the previous, less specific selector `.highlight`. Instead of using the shorthand in `.highlight#<id>`, you could use it to set background defaults on all `.highlight` elements, then be specific when declaring the image, for example:

```
.highlight {
  ...
  background: no-repeat center / cover;
}

.highlight#pixel {
  background-image: url('../images/pixel.jpg');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by reverse the rules? `.highlight#pixel` first, then `.highlight` or do you mean the shorthand `background: ...` first and then the specific rule: `background-image: url()` as you did in above answer?

Comment: I'll clarify in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `background` shorthand CSS will overwrite all background properties you have under `.highlight`. For your id specific divs, use the full background properties and not the shortand.

```
.highlight#pixel
{
    background-image: url('');
    ...
}
```

for example.